Isoperimetric Problem Proof Question
Consider the isoperimetric problem where we seek the optimal $y(x)$, with $y(a) = y(b) = 0$, for the functional:
\begin{align}
F[y(x)] = \int_a^b f(x, y, y') dx  
\tag{1}
\end{align}
subject to the constraint
\begin{align}
G[y(x)] = \int_a^b g(x, y, y') dx = 0
\tag{2}
\end{align}
The standard way in which one solves this problem is to use the Euler-Lagrange equation for the unconstrained functional:
\begin{align}
H[y(x)] = \int_a^b f(x, y, y') + \lambda g(x, y, y') dx
\tag{3}
\end{align}
,where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier, to be determined by substituting the optimal $y(x)$ into the constraint equation (2).
Does anyone have a good reference that shows how to arrive at equation (3)?
P.S. I come from a physics background and I found a couple of references (such as p.83 of Bruce van Brunt "The Calculus of Variations", and this), however, I believe these proofs are flawed.

I believe a proof is given in Sec. 2.5 of Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory by Liberzon. Optimal Control of Partial Differential Equations by Troltzsch also contains some very detailed proofs of related results in its opening chapters.

Great, I figured out what the problem was, thanks!
